# clicking is forbidden on canvas

Tags: canvas, click, html5-canvas

I need to prevent clicking in some places of the canvas. For example; the canvas below. Between (0,250)-(0,300) coordinates as (x,y), if the user click anywhere in this interval nothing is gonna be.

```
<script>

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('lbltipAddedComment').innerHTML = '  ';
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
}
</script>

<div id="ccontainer">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The canvas does not respond to clicks on its own. It needs code to do so. So as it stands, clicking is forbidden on the entire canvas by default. Your code will enable it to react to clicks. So just write your code to react to clicks in the way you want it to.

An easy way to do this would be position a transparent html element over the canvas (position it using CSS). Set an on-click handler, perhaps using JQuery, so when that transparent element is clicked, it performs the operation you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am newbie in html coding, so I can't understand completely. I have different items on the forbidden zone on canvas. Clicking event should be dynamic in my project. I can click everywhere on canvas at first and then clicking will be forbidden in some places.

Comment: If the user is clicking on objects drawn by the canvas then you'd probably be better off using something else, I strongly recommend getting into using Raphael.js because it allows assigning click handlers to specific objects, then you can remove the clickability at will, and in particular, have click regions correlate with the objects.